# importar columna fecha desde excel en laravel 5.6 usando maatwebsite 3.1

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite

Saludosa todos, estoy intentando importar un fichero excel para la base de datos, uso  `maatwebsite\laravel` excel 3.1 tengo el siguiente código implementado en el `import`:

```
class ImportExcel implements ToModel
{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Service([
            'number_service'=>$row[0],
            'service'=>$row[1],
'entry_date'=>\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($row[2]),
    ]);
    }
```

al importarlo me da el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si alguien tiene alguna idea y quiere tomarse la molestia en ayudarme se lo voy agradecer.

Este es el fichero de excel donde tengo los datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa que el formato de fecha de la clase \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject         
conicida con el formato de fecha que estas importando desde el Excel

Comment: Ya cambié el formato de excel a 2019-05-18 como aparece en la clase PhpOffice, pero sigue dando el mismo error de la imagen anterior

Comment: Y el error no esta en el campo 'numero_servicio' ?

Comment: el campo numero_servicio No es de fecha es un auto numerico, que me escribe un consecutivo seguido del año en curso. Gracias por tomarse las molestias al final lo que hice fue bajar a maatwebsite 2.1.0, ya sé que es mas viejo pero funciona de maravilla. no sé porqué con él 3.1 me da esos errores. Gracias de todas formas.